# Extract a submatrix consisting

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose that `A` is a 10 × 10 matrix. We want to extract a submatrix consisting of rows 2 to 7 and columns 2 to 6 of A. What single MATLAB command (using 10 characters or less) could accomplish this? `A` has already been defined.

My answer is

```
B=A([2:7],[2:6])
```

But this is apparently wrong. This solution needs 10 characters or less. `(2:7, 2:6)` is wrong as well.

Comment: As you've found, you don't need the square brackets.  I summize that you are not supposed to have the `B=` either.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
A = magic(10);B = A(2:7,2:6)

B =

80     7    14    16    73
81    88    20    22    54
87    19    21     3    60
93    25     2     9    61
24    76    83    90    42
 5    82    89    91    48
```

Works just fine. Are you able to post your problem in more context, and show the error you are getting? `A(2:7, 2:6)` is perfectly standard MATLAB syntax.